# Is there a way to store KMS CMK in a cache for encryption

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I want to store KMS CMK to be stored in a cache to reduce calls to KMS everytime I store my data in S3 and in DynamoDb.

Storing it in Boto3core cache didnt worked for me, also lru cache didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can enable an [S3 bucket key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-key.html) to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 0):

#### Amazon S3

You can use [Amazon S3 Bucket Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-key.html), instead of encrypting each file individually. S3 handles the caching of the key on your behalf and can reduce the calls to KMS by up to 99%.

> When you configure your bucket to use an S3 Bucket Key for SSE-KMS, AWS generates a short-lived bucket-level key from AWS KMS then temporarily keeps it in S3. This bucket-level key will create data keys for new objects during its lifecycle. S3 Bucket Keys are used for a limited time period within Amazon S3, reducing the need for S3 to make requests to AWS KMS to complete encryption operations. This reduces traffic from S3 to AWS KMS, allowing you to access AWS KMS-encrypted objects in Amazon S3 at a fraction of the previous cost.

#### Amazon DynamoDB

In DynamoDB there is no need to cache keys, as it uses similar caching to S3's bucket key. To reduce costs for KMS on DynamoDB you should ensure good connection handling.

- Ensure TCP Keep-Alive is True
- Re-use your client
- Avoid creating clients for each invocation of a method
- If you use Lambda, ensure you create your client outside of the request handler